# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Journey Builder - Unknown Custom Action

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I just started a role as a SFMC admin, doing a health check of current instance. In the journey builder there are many journeys with a white box called "Unknown Custom Journey" what does this mean? Is this standard?

Answer (score 0):

Without having much history on the account, it's hard to pinpoint exactly what has gone wrong. What I suspect is that there was a custom activity there and the web server hosting it is down (or has been switched off). I would check the page through the network tab in developer tools for more information.